# Making Multiview Button Tappable

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uitapgesturerecognizer

This is currently a `UIStackView` with a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`.

I want the entire thing to be tappable.

[image]

My poor man's solution at the moment is to overlay a `UIView` on top of the `UIStackView` and add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` into the mix. But it sucks imo.

If I add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to `UIStackView`, nothing happens because subviews fill up the `UIStackView`.

What is best practice to turn this into a button?

Comment: Can you show initialization code or storyboard?

Comment: I don't see why you cannot do the same with UIButtons. You can have your UIButtons that look exactly the same as your UIView and UILabel, and you would be solving the issue without having to come up with a "hack" to make a UIView Subclass tappable.

Comment: Well, he's certainly right in the sense that a UIButton _is_ a UIImageView plus a UILabel already. But arranging them to look like what your stack view gives you might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: @matt not sure I follow. Are you suggesting that I do use UIButton or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nothing happens because subviews fill up the UIStackView.

Right, but if you turn off the `userInteractionEnabled` of those subviews, the touch falls through to the UIStackView and the gesture recognizer attached to the UIStackView will work.

Comment: @EricJohnson remember that this solution won't give you the look and feel of a button. The end user won't get the expected behavior of tapping into what is supposed to be a button.

Comment: a tap is a tap. What specific behavior are you referring to? @IOSAddicted